# Calculate total and average sales

Tags: c#, arrays, variable-assignment

The assignment is as follows:

> Total Sales
>
> Use the attached file named Sales.txt.  Create an application that
>
> - reads the file’s content into an array of double or decimal
> - displays the array’s content in a ListBox control,
> - calculates the total of the array’s values, average sales, largest sales, smallest sales
> - Display the Total Sales, Average sales, Highest Sales and Smallest Sales
> - Form should look similar to the following:
>
> [image]

How do I get the data to display the `Total`/`Average`/`High`/`Low` Sales part of the image to display properly by typing the corresponding code?

I'd like to do this on my own so if you could provide an example that might relate to what I am doing that would really help.

Here's what I've been able to type up so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace Total_Sales
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //declaring array
            const int SIZE = 100;
            decimal[] sales = new decimal[SIZE];

            //varible to hold amount stored in array
            int count = 0;

            decimal additionHolder = 0;

            //declaring streamreader
            StreamReader inputFile;

            //opening the sales file
            inputFile = File.OpenText("../../Sales.txt");

            try
            {
                //pull contents from file into array while there is still items
                //to pull and the array isnt full
                while (!inputFile.EndOfStream && count < sales.Length)
                {
                    sales[count] = decimal.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                    count++;
                }
                //close the file
                inputFile.Close();

                //display contents in listbox
                for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
                {
                    ListBox.Items.Add(sales[index]);
                }

                
                //add all the values
                for (int index = 0; index < sales.Length; index++)
                {
                    additionHolder += sales[index];
                }
                
                
            }

             
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could use a `List` instead of an `array` and you should use `Linq` to calculate totals, min etc.

Comment: I will give that a try, thank you.

Comment: My textbook doesn't have anything on how to do linq to calculate totals in C#. http://www.amazon.com/Starting-Visual-2012-CD-Rom-Edition/dp/0133129454

Comment: using `linq`, if I'm not wrong You can get, for example, sum `var total = sales.Sum();` (not sure is it correct code for `c#`, I prog. in vb.net)... Same for minimum (`sales.Min();`), average `sales.Average();`... and so on.

Comment: What's the purpose of the exercise then? Learning C#? Learning winforms? Are you restricted to material in the text book? If you cannot use `Linq`, e.g. `sales.Average()`, you could keep track of the min and max sales while reading the lines and calculate the average yourself.

Comment: It's to get me to learn how to use arrays and to be able to recreate the image shown. So far I've got the listbox to display the values from the Sales.txt file. All I have left to do is make each lblBox to display Totals, Average, Highest, Smallest from the values in the Sales.txt file. As for the sql tag that was an error on my part, new to this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two solutions. The first using an `array`, the second using a `List`. In both example's I presume that the textboxes for total, average, min and max sales are called `TotalSales`, `AverageSales`, `MinSales` and `MaxSales`.

```
private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    const int SIZE = 100;
    decimal[] sales = new decimal[SIZE];

    int count = 0;
    decimal totalSales, averageSales, minSales, maxSales;

    StreamReader inputFile;
    inputFile = File.OpenText("../../Sales.txt");

    try
    {
        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream && count < sales.Length)
        {
            sales[count] = decimal.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
            minSales = count == 0 ? sales[count] : Math.Min(minSales, sales[count]);
            maxSales = count == 0 ? sales[count] : Math.Max(maxSales, sales[count]);
            totalSales += sales[count];
            ListBox.Items.Add(sales[count]);
            count++;
        }

        inputFile.Close();
        averageSales = totalSales / sales.Length;  

        TotalSales.Text = totalSales;
        AverageSales.Text = averageSale;
        MinSales.Text = minSales;
        MaxSales.Text = maxSales;
    }              
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Using a `List` and `Linq`:

```
private void displayButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<decimal> sales = new List<decimal>(); // notice: no size limitation

    StreamReader inputFile;
    inputFile = File.OpenText("../../Sales.txt");

    try
    {
        while (!inputFile.EndOfStream)
        {
            var sale = decimal.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine()); 
            sales.Add(sale);
            ListBox.Items.Add(sale);
        }

        inputFile.Close();

        TotalSales.Text = sales.Sum();
        AverageSales.Text = sales.Average();
        MinSales.Text = sales.Min();
        MaxSales.Text = sales.Max();
    }              
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

As you can see this code is much more concise.

BTW, I wrote this code without Visual Studio at hand so it might contain some typo's.

Comment: Thank you for the input. Yeah I like how concise it is.

Answer (score 0):

After you read values from file just use Linq methods and set Text property of yours TextBox controls.

```
var total = sales.Sum();
var avg = sales.Average();
var min = sales.Min();
var max = sales.Max();

totalTextBox.Text = total.ToString(); //example for TextBox named totalTextBox
```

remember to add using :)

```
using System.Linq;
```

Comment: I finished it. I appreciate everyone's feedback.